# Java Jersey for RESTful web services

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, jersey

I am using Java Jersey to write web services for my app and am having some problems with the cofiguration. When I call my service as given below, it says:

> message Method Not Allowed
>   description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Method Not Allowed).

Sample request:

```
localhost:8080/MovieManager/rest/movies?movie_count=2&country_code=USA
```

Here are my Service source file and web.xml file:

```
package com.recommendation.movies;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
public class MovieData {

@GET
@Path("movies")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getMovies (@QueryParam("movie_count") int movieCount, @QueryParam("country_code") String countryCode) {

String moviesJson = null; // This has the JSON list of all movies returned by the external service
// DO SOMETHING...      
// returned the customized json string...
return moviesJson;
}
```

}

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>Movie Manager</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Get Top Box Office Movie Listing</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.recommendation.movies</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Get Top Box Office Movie Listing</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Do you  `GET` this URL? Do you `Accept` `text/plain`?

Comment: I am just running this in a browsre which I am sure GETs this URL and should be able to receive any text/plain response.

Comment: are you also seeing "HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed" ?

Answer (score 2):

What's the version of Jersey ?

Because ... I used this, and it works !

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.application.sinister</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Try also

```
 @Path("/test")
```

And use the following url :

```
 localhost:8080/MovieManager/rest/test/movies?movie_count=2&country_code=USA
```

Answer (score 0):

it is strange how I managed to fix this problem, but here is the solution:

Instead of using a:

```
 @Path("/")
```

When I replaced it with a:

```
@Path("search_movie/")
```

and called the API with the updated URI, it works.